# Get the all the process names with process id in linux

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am trying with the below options

1.copied the data i need in text from out put of

```
ps ax -o rss,command | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

2.But this output contains extract like below

```
856232 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/data/vmware/server/xxxxx/conf/logging.properties -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -Xss256k -
```

but i need the string only after `/data/vmware/server` ie `xxxxx`.

i tried sed and awk but not getting intended ones.

Comment: You've been asking questions here for a while. Try to format them properly, give feedback to the answerers and eventually accept an answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Use grep.

```
ps ax -o rss,command | sort -nr | head -n 10 | grep -oP 'data/vmware/server/\K[^/]*'
```

Example:

```
$ echo '856232 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/data/vmware/server/xxxxx/conf/logging.properties -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -Xss256k -' | grep -oP 'data/vmware/server/\K[^/]*'
xxxxx
```

**OR**

sed.

```
$ echo '856232 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/data/vmware/server/xxxxx/conf/logging.properties -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -Xss256k -' | sed 's~.*data/vmware/server/\([^/]*\).*~\1~'
xxxxx
```

Comment: Go for the `grep` version.. the `awk` command isn't reliable - if the location of java changes, `{10}` might point to a different part.

Comment: note you can use `awk '...' <<< "string"` instead of `echo "string" | awk '...'`. This helps to show the relevant code instead of the echo